# MS Edge invokes controller action multiple times

Tags: model-view-controller, microsoft-edge

I have a VS2017 MVC web application that returns a FileResult from one of its actions. Firefox, IE, and Chrome correctly invoke DisplayPDF() once. The Microsoft Edge browser incorrectly invokes the action multiple times. Why is this occurring?

Here is the controller action:

```
    public FileResult DisplayPDF()
    {
        Logger.debug("Home DisplayPDF() invoked");
        string zFileu = Server.MapPath(@"~/APP_DATA/tmp/") + "test.pdf";
        return File(zFileu, "application/pdf");

    }
```

The Index.cshtml file follows:

```
@{
Layout = null;
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<html>
<body>
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Display A PDF", "DisplayPDF", "Home")
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with your code but I am not able to produce the issue on my end.

Below is my testing result.

[image]

Is this the exact code that you are using on your side?

Also try to check whether there are any other references calling the same function or not.

For testing purpose, create a new MVC project and just add above code in it and run it to check whether you can produce the similar issue or not.

If you are able to produce the same issue then you can try to repair the MS Edge application and then try to install the latest updates for it. It may help you to solve your issue.

Let us know about your testing result.

Comment: That is the exact code on the server side. The only other code is the logger. The error is easily reproduced by setting a breakpoint. In Edge, the log shows entry into the controller action 2 times.

Comment: Please try setting a breakpoint at the entry to PDFDisplay(). Click the hyperlink and step through via PF10. I was returned into the action multiple times before the PDF would display. That is how I found this problem. I even commented out the Logger and reproduced the problem.